# How to get data from eBay Notifications

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ebay-api

I was following the tutorial by [Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/writing-an-api/). I am using it to create a route/API with Meteor that will receive the notifications from eBay. But the problem I'm having is, the request.body that I receive from eBay is an empty object. I can see the headers it sends me just fine in the request where it has soapaction [AskSellerQuestion](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/features-guide/content/notifications/Notif-AskSellerQuestion.html). (I was testing it by asking a question, so it seems to work)

Where exactly in the request for eBay Notifications do I find the XML that has the information about the notification? Or am I going about it in the wrong way? I have found that eBay's documentation is not very helpful.

My code that was requested:

This is my api.js

```
API = {

   authentication: function( apiKey ) {
      // Authenticate with the app's API Key
      var getKey = Meteor.settings.auroraAPIKey;
      if ( apiKey === getKey ) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }

   },
   connection: function( request, key ) {
      var getRequestContents = API.utility.getRequestContents( request ),
          //apiKey             = getRequestContents.api_key,
          validUser          = API.authentication( key );

      if ( validUser ) {
         //delete getRequestContents.api_key;
         // return data
         // This object is refered to as 'connection.data'
         return { owner: 'Aurora', data: getRequestContents };
      } else {
         return { error: 401, message: "Invalid API key." };
      }
   },
   handleRequest: function( context, resource, method, key ) {
      var connection = API.connection( context.request, key );
      if ( !connection.error ) {
         API.methods[ resource ][ method ]( context, connection );
      } else {
         API.utility.response( context, 401, connection );
      }
   },

   methods: {
      ebay: {
         GET: function( context, connection ) {},
         POST: function( context, connection ) {

            // HERE: is where I want to access the request.body but it is empty

            console.log( connection.data, context.request );
            // Response of 200 is required for eBay Notifications
            API.utility.response( context, 200, connection.data );

            let soapaction = context.request.headers.soapaction;
            let split = soapaction.split( '/notification/' );
            let notification = split[ 1 ];

            EbayNotifications.insert(
               {
                  createdAt: new Date(),
                  soapaction: soapaction,
                  notification: notification
               }
            );
         },
         PUT: function( context, connection ) {},
         DELETE: function( context, connection ) {}
      }
   },

   utility: {
      getRequestContents: function( request ) {
         switch( request.method ) {
            case "GET":
               return request.query;
            case "POST":
            case "PUT":
            case "DELETE":
               return request.body;
         }
      },
      hasData: function( data ) {
         return Object.keys( data ).length > 0 ? true : false;
      },
      response: function( context, statusCode, data ) {
         context.response.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
         context.response.statusCode = statusCode;
         context.response.end( JSON.stringify( data ) );
      },
      validate: function( data, pattern ) {
         return Match.test( data, pattern );
      }
   }

};
```

This is my route:

```
Router.route( '/api/ebay/:key', function () {
   this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
   // https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll

   if ( this.request.method === "OPTIONS" ) {
      this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' );
      this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS' );
      this.response.end( 'Set OPTIONS.' );
   } else {
      API.handleRequest( this, 'ebay', this.request.method, this.params.key );
   }
}, { where: 'server' });
```

This successfully receives the eBay platform notifications. I am just not sure where to access the XML, since the request.body is blank. I have searched google endlessly for the information I need. eBay has docs: [SetNotificationPreferences](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/SetNotificationPreferences.html), [Working With Platform Notifications](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/features-guide/default.html#notifications/notifications.html), and [Getting Notifications](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/howto/Notifications/Notifications_listing.html) I have checked out but don't seem to help my situation.

Edit once again: this is what I AM getting in the request when I log it:

```
{} { _readableState: 
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { close: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: 32,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 4987,
     _bytesDispatched: 1231,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 6,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:8080' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: null,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 14384,
        _bytesDispatched: 1798,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1453475881306,
        _monotonicStartTime: 898918969,
        pipe: [Function],
        addListener: [Function: addListener],
        on: [Function: addListener],
        pause: [Function],
        resume: [Function],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1453475881568,
     _monotonicStartTime: 898919231,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        write: [Function],
        end: [Function] } },
  connection: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: 32,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 4987,
     _bytesDispatched: 1231,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 6,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:8080' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: null,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 14384,
        _bytesDispatched: 1798,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1453475881306,
        _monotonicStartTime: 898918969,
        pipe: [Function],
        addListener: [Function: addListener],
        on: [Function: addListener],
        pause: [Function],
        resume: [Function],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1453475881568,
     _monotonicStartTime: 898919231,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        write: [Function],
        end: [Function] } },
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: 
   { host: '/*...omitted...*/',
     'user-agent': 'eBayNioHttpClient 1.0',
     'content-length': '2840',
     'cache-control': 'max-age=86400',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=utf-8',
     soapaction: '"http://developer.ebay.com/notification/AskSellerQuestion"',
     via: '1.1 phx7b02c-718782 (squid)',
     'x-forwarded-for': '/*...omitted...*/',
     'x-forwarded-proto': 'http',
     'x-mod-region': '/*...omitted...*/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip' },
  trailers: {},
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  url: '/api/ebay//*...omitted...*/',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  client: 
   { _connecting: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: 32,
        writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        reading: true },
     _readableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: false,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        calledRead: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        objectMode: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _writableState: 
      { highWaterMark: 16384,
        objectMode: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        buffer: [],
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     onend: [Function],
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 4987,
     _bytesDispatched: 1231,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _connections: 6,
        connections: [Getter/Setter],
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:8080' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext: 
      { _connecting: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        onend: null,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 14384,
        _bytesDispatched: 1798,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 1453475881306,
        _monotonicStartTime: 898918969,
        pipe: [Function],
        addListener: [Function: addListener],
        on: [Function: addListener],
        pause: [Function],
        resume: [Function],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 1453475881568,
     _monotonicStartTime: 898919231,
     parser: 
      { _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        onHeaders: [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        onHeadersComplete: [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        onBody: [Function: parserOnBody],
        onMessageComplete: [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function] },
     ondata: [Function],
     _paused: false,
     _httpMessage: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: 10,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _headerSent: false,
        _header: '',
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        write: [Function],
        end: [Function] } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  upgrade: false,
  originalUrl: '/api/ebay//*...omitted...*/',
  _parsedUrl: 
   { protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/api/ebay//*...omitted...*/',
     path: '/api/ebay//*...omitted...*/',
     href: '/api/ebay//*...omitted...*/' },
  query: {},
  body: {} }
```

Comment: you need to provide the code that you've written for this and some links to the specific eBay documentation you've consulted, otherwise it's much harder for someone to help you. thanks!

Comment: I didn't think either were necessary. My question is where in the response that eBay sends I can find the XML. Because the response.body is empty.

Comment: @omouse Okay I have added the requested information. I would find it helpful if anyone who is going to downvote the question would provide some information on why they down voted. I am just trying to get some help .Thank you :)

Comment: in which part of the code are you trying to access the response from ebay? Could you put something like `// HERE: is where I want to access the response.body but it is empty`, will be easier to help you that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an event on the response called 'data' which is triggered whenever the response has data. We can get the response status code very quickly but the data may take some time to load.

Try this:

```
response.on('data', function handleResponse(data) {
  console.log("data from the response");
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I meant to say in the request not response, my mistake. But I tried adding that function and it did not log anything. I am editing my question with what IS getting logged (I am logging the request). I also added the comment where I am trying to log it/access the data.

Comment: I FINALLY got it to work :) I did use your answer but it took me so long and so many tries to get it to log what I wanted. I re wrote my route and used this after response.end(), and it seemed to do the trick. Thank you for your help